# Circumscribing simplex to convex body?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry

> **Q**.
>   Does every (perhaps smooth) compact convex body $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ admit a
>   circumscribing simplex, each facet of which touches (shares a point with) $K$?
>   How about a circumscribing *regular* simplex?

This question is inspired by this result (in a paper I have yet to access):

> Shizuo Kakutani. 
>   "A proof that there exists a circumscribing cube around any bounded
>   closed convex set in $\mathbb{R}^3$."
>   *Ann. Math.*, 43(4):739–741, 1942.

Perhaps the regular simplex question is answered already in $\mathbb{R}^2$?
If so, I would appreciate a reference. Thanks!

---

[image: EqTriCircum]

---

**Answered** by Wlodzimierz Holsztynski in the comments: *Yes*, every $K$ has (many)
circumscribing regular simplices.

Comment: In $\ \mathbb R^2\ $ just move the lines till they touch the convex body. You can position your regular simplex (equilateral triangle) in every possible direction.

Comment: The same must be true in dimension $n$. When you move faces (each independently) of a regular simplex in parallel, the simplex stays regular (just make sure that the intersection of the chosen open half-spaces stays non-empty).

Comment: You may want to take a look at the references mentioned by Prof. Hatcher in his answer to the following question of mine: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26318/points-on-a-sphere

Comment: I've just edited the link...

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski: "the simplex stays regular": Very nice!!

Comment: Thank you Joseph. Indeed, in $\ \mathbb R^n,\ $ when one vertex is fixed, and we move the opposite opposite plane then according to Thales we get a homothetic simplex (hence regular if we started with a regular simplex).

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski: I like to believe that Thales would be pleased to be cited in this context, 2,500 years later. :-)

Comment: I gave a bound for the volume of such a simplex in http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00013-014-0616-6 It is interesting to ask about regular simplex case.

Comment: Note the dual question:  

**Q'** *Does every  compact convex body $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ admit an inscribed regular simplex, each vertex of which lies in the boundary of $L$* ? 

While **Q** admits the simple construction by moving planes described above, it is not obvious to me how the dual construction should work for the answer of **Q'**.

Comment: Precisely: it is not obvious (to me) that a simplex growing inside $L$ can in fact keep growing till all its vertices have reached the boundary of $L$. But the positive answer to **Q** implies a positive answer to **Q'** by duality, right?

Comment: @PietroMajer: I think what's missing here is that indeed the polar dual w.r.t. the simplex centroid maps to a simplex inscribed in the dual shape, but not all convex bodies can be obtained through this duality.

Comment: Atsushi (above) proved: There is a simplex $S$ with Vol$(S) \le \;d^{d-1}$Vol$(K)$.