# Is this generalization of Borsuk Ulam true? Roots of unity

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Consider a continous map from $S^2$ to $C$.

Is it true that there exists 3 points equially spaced on a great circle, $x_1,x_2,x_3$, such that if $w$ is the third root of unity, $f(x_1)+wf(x_2)+w^2f(x_3)=0$?

More generally I'm asking this if we take nth unity roots.

Maybe I should add slight motivation: In my topology course we were shown a proof of borsuk ulam that goes through defining $g(x)=(f(x)-f(-x))/(|f(x)-f(-x)|)$, then by looking at it on the great circle, we can lift it to a function to $R$ satisfying (here we view $g$ as a function from $[0,1]$ instead of from the circle, and taking $x+1/2$ mod 1 in the next expression) $g(x+1/2)=n+1/2+g(x)$ for some natural $n$, but since it is continous, this is the same $n$ for all $x$. In particular $g(1)=2n+1+g(0)$ and thus this is a nontrivial path on the circle, but it homotopic to the constant one via returning to the sphere and wrapping the circle around to a constant function.

Then notice the argument after the lift works the same when we know $g(x+1/3)=n+1/3+g(x)$. However there is no direct analong we can do to reach the part of lifting, because that would involve choosing for each point a great circle it is contained in a way that partions the sphere into great circles which is clearly impossible.

If this turns out to be false, is there a space we can do this trick on to get this cute result?

Comment: Does "big circle" means "great circle"?

Comment: @IgorRivin Yes, I'll update.

Comment: I think that your first question can be answered (in the affirmative) by resorting to the first theorem in Shizuo Kakutani's "A proof that there exists a circumscribing cube around any bounded closed convex set in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$" (Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 43, #4, Oct. 1942). You are welcome to take a look at a related question I posed several years ago here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26318/points-on-a-sphere

Comment: @JoséHdz.Stgo. I'm not sure I understand, the paper considers functions to $R$ and proves that there are 3 points which are like the basis for $R^3$ that have the same value, and the question you quote says that we can take arbitary equilateral triangles (on the sphere?).  How does this prove my question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
First, suppose that $G$ acts freely on connected spaces $X$ and $Y$, and that $p\colon X\to Y$ is $G$-equivariant.  We then have a diagram of fibrations
\begin{CD}
     X @>>> X/G @>>> BG \\
     @VpVV @VVV @VV1V \\
     Y @>>> Y/G @>>> BG
\end{CD}
This gives a diagram of fundamental groups
\begin{CD}
     \pi_1(X) @>>> \pi_1(X/G) @>>> G \\
     @Vp_*VV @VVV @VV1V \\
     \pi_1(Y) @>>> \pi_1(Y/G) @>>> G
\end{CD}
and it is not hard to see that the rows are short exact sequences.

Now specialise to the case where $Y=\mathbb{C}^\times$ and $G=C_3$ acting by rotation, and $\pi_1(X)$ is finite.  Using the top row we see that $\pi_1(X/G)$ is also finite, so the only homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial.  On the other hand, bottom row is then $\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{3}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/3$, and this quickly leads to a contradiction.

Now suppose that $f\colon S^2\to\mathbb{C}$ is a counterexample to the OP's question.  Fix three points $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ equally spaced on a great circle.  Let $R$ be the rotation that sends $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ to $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_1$.  Define $p\colon SO(3)\to \mathbb{C}^\times$ by 
$$ p(T) = f(Tx_1) + \omega f(Tx_2) + \omega^2 f(Tx_3), $$
and note that this satisfies $g(TR)=\omega^{-1}g(T)$.  In other words, if we let $C_3$ act on $SO(3)$ using $R$ and on $\mathbb{C}^\times$ by $\omega^{-1}$, we see that $p$ is equivariant.  This is impossible by our initial lemma, because $\pi_1(SO(3))=\mathbb{Z}/2$.

All the above still works if we replace $3$ by another integer $n>1$.

Comment: Hi, I am very sad to say I don't know enough about topology to understand your answer, but it motivates very much to learn about it. (I accepted your answer assuming that upvotes from other people verify your solution).

Comment: Are you proving that there is no a free action of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. If yes how this solve the OP question? Moreover I think there is an easy argument for non existence of such free action, as I learn in the book by Allen Hatcher: n=2 is the only $n$ such that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ can act freely on a even domensional sphere. The proof is simply based on the degree of maps. The "degree" is a group isomirphism from $G$ to$ {1,-1}$ (Counting $g\in G$ as a homeomorphism of even sphere. On the other hand a fixed point free homeomorphism has degree -1.

Comment: @AliTaghavi There are no even spheres involved here at all.  There is a free action of $C_3$ on $SO(3)$ (which is almost the same as $S^3$) and a free action of $C_3$ on $\mathbb{C}^\times$ (which is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$).  There is no issue about the existence of these actions, the point is to prove that there is no $C_3$-equivariant map $SO(3)\to \mathbb{C}^\times$.

Comment: @NeilStrickland  So my apology for not reading your answer, carefully.I read it again.I am on my phon.